# search and replace: remember case in substitute

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I have to change strings:

- `fetchrandomData` to `fetchReportingData`
- `FETCH_RANDOM_DATA` to `FETCH_REPORTING_DATA`

I can change `ca_z` and `CA_Z` to `ca_t` and `CA_T` respectively with command:

`%s/\v([Cc])([Az])(_)?([Tt])/\1\2\3\4/gci`.

For a string with 3 or more characters this method seems unfeasible, let alone for string `FETCH_RANDOM_DATA` of length 17 characters.

What is more a feasible way to do something like this in vim?

Comment: What does this have to do with sed, exactly? (Although I would take a look at tpope’s Abolish plugin, it handles this nicely.)

Comment: Agreed @Rich , the second is a change of words and has nothing to with case. The first doesn’t change the word but does modify the case.

Comment: As well as remembering the case you also want to remember the presence or absence of underscores?

Comment: Is the `r` in `random` in your first example still lowercase deliberately?

Comment: Yes. Using command `s/\vfetch(_)?random(\1)?/fetch\1Reporting\1/gci`, I end up with `fetch_Reporting_DATA` for `FETCH_RANDOM_DATA`. The first example `fetchrandomData` is replaced successfully with `fetchReportingData`